# How to implement v2ray client using flutter

Tags: flutter, vpn

Is there a way to implement v2ray using only flutter and not native code? I found some vpn packages and source codes but they do not use v2ray or they are using native languages too.

Comment: You can use [libv2ray](https://pub.dev/packages/libv2ray) flutter package.